# Azure Artifacts feed for public npm module

Tags: azure, node-modules, azure-artifacts, azure-git-deployment, .npmrc

I have publish a npm module over Azure Artifacts Feed, which works fine with he generated npmrc. I understand that I can update the permission configurations to restrict the access for users too.

But, I want to have a npm module which won't need any npmrc published over my Azure Git Organisation. Is it possible? If so how?